# Show alert on successfull fetch request in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am updating a user in my **react & redux** application. And on successfull update i.e fetch (PUT) request, I want to show an alert message "User is successfully updated". But I am not getting any way to do the same. Below is my component, action & reducer code.

**userComponent.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {updateUserData} from '../redux/actions/user';

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
    return{
        updating_user_pending: state.usersData.updating_user_pending,
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>{
    return{
        updateUserAction: (data) =>{dispatch(updateUserData(data))}
    }
}

Class Users extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
      super();
      this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    onSubmit(values) {
      this.props.updateUserAction(values);
    }

    render(){
      return(
         <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label className="label">First Name</label>
              <Field className="form-control" name="first_name" component="input" type="text" />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label className="label">Email</label>
              <Field className="form-control" name="email" component="input" type="email" />
            </div>

            <button className="btn btn-primary">{(updating_user_pending)?'Submitting...':'Submit'}</button>
         </form>
      );  
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Users);
```

**action.js**

```
export function updateUserData(data){
    return function(dispatch){
        dispatch({type: UPDATE_USER_PENDING});
        fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users/'+data.user_id, {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
        .then(res=>{
            if(res.status===200){
                dispatch({type: UPDATE_USER_SUCCESS});
            }else{
                dispatch({type: UPDATE_USER_FAILED});
            }
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            dispatch({type: UPDATE_USER_FAILED});            
        })
    }
}
```

**reducer.js**

```
import {
    UPDATE_USER_PENDING,
    UPDATE_USER_SUCCESS,
    UPDATE_USER_FAILED
} from '../actions/action-types';

const initialState = {
    updating_user_pending:false
}

const userReducer = function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case UPDATE_USER_PENDING:
            return {
               ...state,
               updating_user_pending: true
            }
        case UPDATE_USER_SUCCESS:
            return {
               ...state,
               updating_user_pending: false
            }
        case UPDATE_USER_FAILED:
            return {
               ...state,
               updating_user_pending: false
            }                                    
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}

export default userReducer;
```

So basicall, I want to show the success & error notification on the basis of api responses. Any help on this will be really appreciated.

Comment: Depends on what type of alerts you wznt to show. To you have a notifications state in your app?

Comment: I just waana show a simple "window.alert"

Comment: I will use "react-toastify" for future. But for now, Just a simple alert

Comment: To show the window.alert just place it when you dispatch the update user success

Comment: To properly using the notifications and react-toastify, i advice that you create a separate redux state in your app dedicated only for notifications. And dispatch an' action that registers your notification

Comment: I don't want to place window.alert inside action. Can you please show an example of How to do the same inside component?

Comment: Sorry im on bed right now :)

Comment: Basically, you create a notifications container connected to a notifications store. The reducer contains two cases: add_notification that takes a message and an id from the payload, and a remove_notification by id that removes the notification

Comment: The notifications containers is placed somewhere in you tree. It maps over the notifications and displays a toasts for each one, and on close of each notification it dispatches a remove notification action

Comment: When your edit user request succeeds/fails, you dispatch an add_notification action with the content tou want to show

Comment: Please try to answer when you will be available.

Comment: Ok first thing in the lorning. Do you use hooks? Please leave your packages versions

Comment: Actually junius wrote a good answer it should do the work

Comment: Hmm, But what If I want to handle the error alert too?

Comment: Hello, did you resolved your issue?

Comment: No, I am finding a better way to solve it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

Show the toast in your action function

```
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

export function updateUserData(data) {
return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch({ type: UPDATE_USER_PENDING });
    fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users/' + data.user_id, {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    .then(res => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
        dispatch({ type: UPDATE_USER_SUCCESS });
        // here
        toast.success("User updated");
        } else {
        dispatch({ type: UPDATE_USER_FAILED });
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        dispatch({ type: UPDATE_USER_FAILED });
    });
};
}
```

In your UserComponent import

```
import { ToastContainer} from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css'
 // ... your code
render(){
  return(
     <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label className="label">First Name</label>
          <Field className="form-control" name="first_name" component="input" type="text" />
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
          <label className="label">Email</label>
          <Field className="form-control" name="email" component="input" type="email" />
        </div>

        <button className="btn btn-primary">{(updating_user_pending)?'Submitting...':'Submit'}</button>
     <ToastContainer />
     </form>
  );
```

[Example from official docs](https://github.com/fkhadra/react-toastify#usage-with-redux)

Comment: Why do I need to create another component for the same? Can't I do it in the User component itself?

Comment: what do you mean by another component? you display the notification in UserComponent

Comment: Yes, It's react-toastify. And fetch request returns either success or error. I want to handle them both.

Comment: Ok, you don't even need another state, just dispatch toast in your action.

Comment: Hmm, I know that. But do you think it's a good practice? As actions are just to dispatch the action & for that I have to create class inside the action file.

Comment: Actually Junius's answer is good and should cover your needs.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you're trying to do here is a "side effect" (or sometimes just "effect").

A side effect is basically a shorter way of saying: "When *X* occurs, also do *Y*". In your case "When "*update success"* also *"show notice"* — "show notice" is a *side effect* of "update success".

Because you probably don't want to put your logic for "show success notice" inside the user form component (because it's not part of the user form), and you also don't want to put it in your reducer (because it's not reducer logic). You want to put it "somewhere else" — *you want to put it in a "side effect"*.

There are a few libraries to help with this "effect business", and since you are using redux; why not have a look at [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/)? Do note though: It's quite a big dependency, some would call it a language in itself. But it's super powerful, especially if you build your application with it in mind.

You could also create your own [redux middleware](https://redux.js.org/api/applymiddleware), where you listen for the `UPDATE_USER_SUCCESS` action, and then act accordingly — Maybe call on anther action named `ADD_SUCCESS_NOTICE` with a message or similar, then have some other component render that notice somewhere — that's usually how I do it.

If you use function components, then you can also use `useEffect` (and other hooks) if you use [react hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

You could also implement some generic notice system, like for instance "toasts". [Here's a tutorial for that](https://react.christmas/2019/20).

Comment: He/she is using actually redux thunk. She/he is asking on a way to integrate notifications into the app. Like having a separate container dedicated only for notifications.

Comment: No, I am not asking to create another container to handle notifications. I want to handle notifications inside User component itself.

Answer (score 0):

UserComponent.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {updateUserData} from '../redux/actions/user';

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
    return{
        updating_user_pending: state.usersData.updating_user_pending,
    }
}
const showResult = () => {
   window.alert('success');
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>{
    return{
        updateUserAction: (data) =>{dispatch(updateUserData(data, showResult))}
    }
}

Class Users extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
      super();
      this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    onSubmit(values) {
      this.props.updateUserAction(values);
    }

    render(){
      return(
         <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label className="label">First Name</label>
              <Field className="form-control" name="first_name" component="input" type="text" />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label className="label">Email</label>
              <Field className="form-control" name="email" component="input" type="email" />
            </div>

            <button className="btn btn-primary">{(updating_user_pending)?'Submitting...':'Submit'}</button>
         </form>
      );  
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Users);
```

action.js

```
export function updateUserData(data, showResult){
    return function(dispatch){
        dispatch({type: UPDATE_USER_PENDING});
        fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users/'+data.user_id, {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
        .then(res=>{
            if(res.status===200){
                dispatch({type: UPDATE_USER_SUCCESS});
                showResult();
            }else{
                dispatch({type: UPDATE_USER_FAILED});
            }
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            dispatch({type: UPDATE_USER_FAILED});            
        })
    }
}
```